# Magento 2 how can I retrive order_uid?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento-community, graphql, magento-commerce

I am using Magento 2.4.2 version. for order return I found graphql here
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/request-return.html

I got 'order_item_uid' by using Customer Order detail graphql. Now I don't have idea how can I get 'order_uid' for orderReturn graphQl API?

Comment: are you using Adobe Commerce ?

Comment: you can check out this 

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/customer.html#order-history